# render :edit causes form URL to change / fail after update

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms, url, routes

I currently have a **working** form that breaks *after* I call `render :edit` in #update. After `render :edit` in #update  **the URL for the #edit page changes** from `questionnaires/1/edit` to `questionnaires/1` .

Unlike most forms, my #edit and #show pages are different pages that represent different steps within this two-part form.  After `render :edit`, any new attempt at saving or submitting fails presumably because #edit (*PUT `questionnaires/1/edit`*) now shares the same route with #show *(GET `questionnaires/1/edit`)*

The form saves properly with redirect_to but in this case I need to use render to retrieve error messages.

## How do I get the persistance of `render` without breaking my form url?

---

Additional Details (if needed):

The form allows users to save or submit changes.  After submission `check_if_finished` is run in Questionnaire.rb to add error messages to the Questionnaire form if any exist.   (Since the form needs to be saveable even when missing fields are present, I avoided using validations with save to generate errors)

```
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HashKey
  
  belongs_to :nanny, foreign_key: :nanny_recruit_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :nanny
  has_one :driving_ability


. . .

  def check_if_finished
    errors.add(:first_name, (custom_error_opening + 'requires answer')) if nanny.first_name.empty?
    errors.add(:last_name, "requires answer") if nanny.last_name.empty?
    errors.add(:preferences, "must select at least one preference") if self.preferences.empty?
  end

. . .
end
```

In my controller the first step of the form is in #edit.  After an #update to #edit, I redisplay the #edit page using *`render :edit`*.  The form saves properly with redirect_to, but I can't use `redirect_to` since that reloads the #edit page without persistance, meaning that my error messages won't show up unless I heavily refactor my errors into something like a Flash message.

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'public'
  before_filter :find_questionnaire, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
  # before_filter :set_commit_param

  # GET /questionnaires/1
  def show
    build_nanny_associations
  end

    # GET /questionnaires/new
    def new
      @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new
      build_nanny_associations
    end

    # GET /questionnaires/1/edit
    def edit
      build_nanny_associations
    end

    # POST /questionnaires
    def create
      @questionnaire = Questionnaire.new(params[:questionnaire])
      if @questionnaire.save
        redirect_to(@questionnaire, :notice => 'Questionnaire was successfully created.')
      else
        render :action => "new"
      end
    end

    # PUT /questionnaires/1
    def update
      update_questionnaire
      render :edit and return unless @questionnaire.valid?
      if params[:commit].match('Next >>')
        @questionnaire.check_if_finished
        render :edit and return unless @questionnaire.errors.empty?
        flash[:success] = ['Questionnaire Step 1 finished!']
        redirect_to questionnaire_path(@questionnaire)
      else
        (flash[:notice] = ['Application Saved!']) + (flash[:info] = questionnaire_url_explanation)
        redirect_to edit_questionnaire_path(@questionnaire)
      end
    end

  # DELETE /questionnaires/1
  def destroy
    @questionnaire.destroy
    redirect_to(questionnaires_url)
  end

  private

  def update_questionnaire
    @questionnaire.update_attributes(params[:questionnaire])
  end

  def build_nanny_associations
    @questionnaire.educations.build if @questionnaire.educations.empty?
    @questionnaire.build_driving_ability
    @questionnaire.driving_ability.driving_ability_cars.build
    if @questionnaire.nanny_times.empty?
      (0..6).to_a.each do |n|
        @questionnaire.nanny_times.build(day: n)
      end
    end
  end

  # def set_commit_param
  #   params[:commit] ||= ""
  # end

  def questionnaire_url_explanation
    ["If you need more time to fill out your application, you can revisit this page by checking the link sent to your email, or by visiting: #{url_for(@questionnaire)} "]
  end

  def find_questionnaire
    NannyRecruit.new # this is here to have rails autoload this class
    @questionnaire = Questionnaire.find_by_hash_key(params[:id])
  end
end
```

For further detail, here's a part of the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@questionnaire, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :nanny do |n| %>
    <%= n.input :first_name %>
    <%= n.input :last_name %>
    ... 
  <% end %>

<div id="driving_ability">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :driving_ability do |da|%>
    <%= render 'questionnaires/driving_ability_fields', :f => da %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

My Rails version is 3.0.9.  Here is the stack trace of the error that only gets generated when I used render :edit:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in QuestionnairesController#update

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'questionnaire_driving_ability_cars.driving_ability_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `questionnaire_driving_ability_cars`.* FROM `questionnaire_driving_ability_cars` WHERE `questionnaire_driving_ability_cars`.`id` IN (8) AND (`questionnaire_driving_ability_cars`.driving_ability_id = 8)


Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

mysql2 (0.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `query'
mysql2 (0.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `block in execute'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:202:in `block in log'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:200:in `log'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record.rb:32:in `block in log_with_newrelic_instrumentation'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_record.rb:29:in `log_with_newrelic_instrumentation'
mysql2 (0.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `execute'
mysql2 (0.2.18) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:586:in `select'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:54:in `block in select_all'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:68:in `cache_sql'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:54:in `select_all'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:473:in `find_by_sql'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:493:in `block in find_by_sql_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_find_by_sql'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:488:in `find_by_sql_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_find_by_sql'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/relation.rb:64:in `to_a'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:143:in `all'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:444:in `all'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:444:in `block in method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1131:in `with_scope'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:212:in `with_scope'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:440:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:364:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:254:in `driving_ability_cars_attributes='
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1569:in `block in attributes='
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1565:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1565:in `attributes='
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:227:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:388:in `assign_to_or_mark_for_destruction'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:296:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:254:in `driving_ability_attributes='
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1569:in `block in attributes='
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1565:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/base.rb:1565:in `attributes='
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:133:in `block in update_attributes'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:493:in `block in transaction_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:488:in `transaction_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:132:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/nanny_application_questionnaires_controller.rb:61:in `update_nanny_application_questionnaire'
app/controllers/nanny_application_questionnaires_controller.rb:35:in `update'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:442:in `block in _run__3469136786962682921__process_action__1830587528925346581__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_48239'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:331:in `around'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:315:in `_callback_around_11'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:220:in `_conditional_callback_around_48239'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:431:in `_run__3469136786962682921__process_action__1830587528925346581__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:262:in `block in perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:257:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:68:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:103:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:499:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:12:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.4.1) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:24:in `call'
pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.20) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.20) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.20) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.20) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.8) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/Users/kelsey/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/kelsey/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/kelsey/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: You need to build_nanny_associations before render. That's why redirecting works. Render doesn't call the controller hence why your getting unknown column

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue!  If you want to add this as an answer I will credit you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build_nanny_associations before render. That's why redirecting works. Render doesn't call the controller hence why your getting unknown column.

Glad it helped